Создать папку с помощью os.mkdir() python
Пишу скрипт на python Windows 11. Импортировал модуль os, использую метод mkdir для создания папки в проекте где находится пайтон файл. Папка создается, никаких ошибок не выдает, но почему-то она не отображается в проекте, ни в vs code, ни в проводнике. Пробовал открыть через окно, которое вызывается клавишами windows+r(не помню название), пишет, что такого файла не существует. Однако, если я запущу программу повторно, выдается ошибка: Такой файл уже существует. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что делать в данной ситуации? Вот кусок кода:
print('Hello, world!')
import os
print(os.getcwd())
try:
    os.mkdir('folder')
except:
    pass
os.chdir('folder')
open('main.py', 'x')


Наверное создается не в том месте, где вы думаете.

Поищите папку там, где находится Python. Или просто начните  поиск с корня диска.

Нет, я пробовал открыть файл в этой папке через функцию open, все получалось без ошибок, даже если пытался в него что-то написать, все-равно без ошибок. Я проверил расположение файла, пайтон говорит, что он там есть, однако ни папки, ни файла я найти не могу

А какие оно должно выдавать ошибки если у вас except: pass

Попробовал даже так: import os try:     os.mkdir('folder') except:     pass os.chdir('folder') print(os.getcwd()) file = open('C:/Users/hablu/Desktop/VSCProjects/OS module/folder/text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') file.write('ojefocjnejn') file = open('C:/Users/hablu/Desktop/VSCProjects/OS module/folder/text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') print(file.read()) Выводит: ojefocjnejn(Текст, написанный в текстовом файле)

У меня Windows 10 и Python 12.4 , код из вопроса работает корректно.

Что выводит команда print(os.getcwd())?

@Григорий скорее всего вы папку создаете в C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3XX

Попробуйте вписать четкий путь до файла, то есть не
os.mkdir('folder')

А вот так:
os.mkdir('C:\...\folder')

